# How to use a plain JS widget in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget, embed

I need to embed a plain JS component that is an input with it's own methods into my React app.
I have a minified `.js` and `.css` file and their `.map` files.

I put them into my static folder and tried to append onto a `<div />` in one of my components in `componentDidMount()` via ref. But it doesn't seems to bundle it with my app. All I see is an empty div with a `<script />` and `<link />` tags.

```
  componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    const link = document.createElement('link')

    script.type = 'text/javascript'
    script.src = 'static/my-component.js'
    script.async = true

    link.href = 'static/my-component.css'
    link.rel = 'stylesheet'

    this.el.appendChild(script)
    this.el.appendChild(link)
  }

render () {
    return (
      <div ref={el => (this.el = el)} />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you can't put the vanilla JS component into your React app. What is the main reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a plugin (ics.js) in the following way

1) I have created a new module in:

`/utilities/ics.js`

```
export const ics = () => {
// plugin code here
}
```

2) from my component, I have imported my plugin

```
import { ics } from './utilities/ics' // use the right path
```

3) In my component, I have used the plugin where i need it:

```
const cal = ics() // works
```

Let me know if this helps.

When it comes to the css, I would simply import it.